# what is flexdashboard trying to download

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am trying to output the flexdashboard template created by Rstudio.
it compiles the .md file and then fails on curl:

Error in curl::curl_download(url, dest, handle = handle, quiet = FALSE,  :
schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed
Calls:  ... dep_func -> read_gfont_url -> download_file ->

this is inside a firewall and github is blocked. CRAN is allowed. if anybody knows what is it that flexdashboard tries to get I can get it and install it in other ways.

````
---
title: "mytitle"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    theme:
      bg: "#101010"
      fg: "#FDF7F7" 
      primary: "#ED79F9"
      base_font:
        google: Prompt
      code_font:
        google: JetBrains Mono
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
# Install thematic and un-comment for themed static plots (i.e., ggplot2)
# thematic::thematic_rmd()
```

Column {data-width=650 .tabset}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart A

```{r}

```

### Chart B

```{r}

```

Column {data-width=350}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart C

```{r}

```

### Chart D

```{r}

```
````

Comment: "flexdashboard template created by Rstudio": can you be more precise?  I can't see where you are getting this...

Answer (score 0):

it is the fonts. after removing the fonts from the title section it can produce output. strangely, it does not work with the fonts even after I downloaded and installed the fonts outside Rstudio.